PyQt Vertical MDI tiled windows
PyQt only seems to have support for Horizontally tiled windows. I would like to tile 2 mdiarea subwindows vertically.  That would be the best approach?
Thank you
Fred

There's only one approach: compute the number of rows and columns, then iterate through subWindowList() and call setGeometry() with each of them.
